# Trying to replicate Habitat menu on Webflow

Tags: navigation, responsive

I am looking for some advice and maybe ideas of how-to replicate a portion Habitat's nav on Webflow.
The portion I am specifically interested in the nested dropdown menus, which upon clicking expand to the right.
Also on mobile this works quite nice, as it saves the space and replaces back button with the previous top category.

I understand this will require some custom code, so I am cool with that, I just need to understand of how it's built.

Also, as the Webflow is closed system, I will be trying to either custom code that portion of the nav, or leverage built-in tools to make it work.

[Habitat's websit](https://www.habitat.co.uk/)

So far I tried to build it on Webflow, but wasn't successful at all.